# jQuery Mobile, open dialog

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, transition

I have a problem to open with transitions jQuery Mobile.

I can not create a transition effect.

Here is my code...

```
    <div id="main" data-role="content" data-theme="d">
<a href="#dialog" data-role="button" data-rel="dialog" data-transition="fade" data-inline="true">dialog</a>
<!-- ... -->
<div data-role="page" id="dialog"><!-- dialog-->
    <div data-role="header" data-theme="e">
        <h1>Foo</h1>
        </div>
    <div data-role="content" data-theme="e">
        <p>Bar</p>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- Footer -->
jQuery('#page').live('pageinit', function() {
    $('.widget ul').attr('data-inset', 'true').attr('data-theme', 'd').attr('data-dividertheme', 'b').attr('data-role', 'listview');
    $('.widget ul').listview();
});
jQuery('#page').live('changepage', function() {
$('#dialog', 'pop', true, true);
});
```

Thanks for your help.

Regards,

V.

Answer (score 6):

On the data-role="page" element, you need to add data-rel="dialog", instead of "id" to get the page to appear as a dialog.

See here: http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/pages/page-dialogs.html

Comment: @adamheaven Thx Adam. I had forgotten "data-rel='dialog'"! :)

Comment: No problem :) I just finished a jquery mobile site myself

Answer (score 1):

```
jQuery(document).delegate('#page', 'pageinit', function() {
    $('.widget ul').attr('data-inset', 'true').attr('data-theme', 'd').attr('data-dividertheme', 'b').attr('data-role', 'listview').listview();
}).delegate('#page', 'changepage', function() {
    $.mobile.changePage('#dialog', {
        transition : 'pop',
        role       : 'dialog'//this means you don't have to declare `data-role="dialog"` on the page if you don't want to
    });
});
```

Notice I chained the `.listview()` function call and the second `.delegate()` function call. I also changed out the `.live()` for `.delegate()` since as of jQuery 1.7, `.live()` is depreciated. To navigate to a page you use `$.mobile.changePage()`: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.0-rc.1/docs/api/methods.html

Comment: Thank you again Jasper. Your expertise is still valuable, you had me already usefully already helped a few days ago.

Comment: is there a way to position this dialog box where you want it to be located?